# django: AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'introspection'

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm using django1.10, python3.4. When trying to use migrations for the first time (Project was django1.6 python2.7), I get the following error:

```
(venv) ruben@erd959:~/Projects/prot-zboss/zboss$ python manage.py makemigrations utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 106, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'introspection'
```

It looks something with the database is not doing ok. Well, It seems that if I remove DATABASE_ROUTERS, it works again but I need to have that for my LDAP functionality.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'prot',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'prot',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '1234',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    },
    'ldap': {
        'ENGINE': 'ldapdb.backends.ldap',
        'NAME': 'ldap://192.168.1.39/',
    }
}


DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ldapdb.router.Router']
```

This is the code of the "ldapdb.router.Router":

```
def is_ldap_model(model):
    # FIXME: there is probably a better check than testing 'base_dn'
    return hasattr(model, 'base_dn')


class Router(object):
    """
    A router to point database operations on LDAP models to the LDAP
    database.

    NOTE: if you have more than one LDAP database, you will need to
    write your own router.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        "Find the name of the LDAP database"
        from django.conf import settings
        self.ldap_alias = None
        for alias, settings_dict in settings.DATABASES.items():
            if settings_dict['ENGINE'] == 'ldapdb.backends.ldap':
                self.ldap_alias = alias
                break

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if 'model' in hints and is_ldap_model(hints['model']):
            return False
        return None

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on LDAP models to the LDAP database"
        if is_ldap_model(model):
            return self.ldap_alias
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on LDAP models to the LDAP database"
        if is_ldap_model(model):
            return self.ldap_alias
        return None
```

Comment: What is ldapdb? Where is it from?

Comment: Add source code of your Router

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I did. I think the problem is that django is taking that connection instead of the default one.

Comment: I think this router doesn't work correctly in your project. Debug and see why